# What is the lldb equivalent of gdb's --args?

Tags: gdb, command-line-arguments, lldb

I'm used to running gdb like so:

```
$ gdb --args exe --lots --of --flags -a -b -c d e
...
(gdb) r
```

Is there an equivalent for lldb?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, it's just `--` instead of `--args`. From the help:

```
lldb -v [[--] <PROGRAM-ARG-1> [<PROGRAM_ARG-2> ...]]
```

Thus:

```
$ lldb -- exe --lots --of --flags -a -b -c d e
```

Comment: Note that if you came here searching for "how to make lldb run my program immediately", you will want to use `lldb -o run -- exe --flags`. Also see [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10586/how-to-run-automatically-executable-from-cli-using-lldb)

Answer (score 7):

You can also start lldb first and use:

```
(lldb) settings set target.run-args 1 2 3
(lldb) run
```

or:

```
(lldb) process launch -- <args>
```

Comment: That was helpful!

Comment: If you want to add option arguments starting with '-' you can use:

`settings set -- target.run-args  "-d"`

Answer (score 0):

just run 'run arg1 arg2' in lldb